# splitting 3 space seperated values in a string from the end of the string?

Tags: python, string

i have this string :

```
"peter bull team tunnel rat 10 20 30"
```

What i would like to do is to extract the last 3 values from the end :

```
 30
 20
 10
```

How can i strip these last 3 fields backwards in python the smartest way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple way would be with `rsplit`:

```
s = "peter bull team tunnel rat 10 20 30"

n = 3
out = s.rsplit(maxsplit=n)[-n:]
# ['10', '20', '30']
```

---

If you want a list of integers:

```
list(map(int, out))
# [10, 20, 30]
```

---

Following the comment, if you want to append the text before the last digits, one way would be:

```
s, *d = s.rsplit(sep=' ',maxsplit=3)
' '.join([*d, s])
# '10 20 30 peter bull team tunnel rat'
```

Comment: what if i want to end up with the original string to end with "peter bull team tunnel rat" - is there a way i can spot what the last position it ended at when it stripped or can it be done smart ?

Comment: Updated. Is the result you expect a string? Otherwise just append both lists @MdTp

Answer (score 1):

you can use split, and reversed() function to get values backwards:

```
data = "peter bull team tunnel rat 10 20 30"

print (list(reversed(data.split()[-3:])))
```

output:

['30', '20', '10']

Answer (score 1):

Using `split()` with list comprehension

- `list.reverse()` - method reverses the elements of a given list.

**Ex.**

```
sentence = "peter bull team tunnel rat 10 20 30"
num = [int(s) for s in sentence.split() if s.isdigit()]
num.reverse()
print(num)
```

**O/P:**

```
[30, 20, 10]
```

Comment: what i would like was to get the 3 values only from the end and then end up with the 3 values + a remaining string that is stripped of the 3 values.

Comment: sort is not used correctly in this case,what if he have string like for example "peter bull team tunnel rat 50 20 30"

Comment: @ncica Please test my code with your string example before commenting here.

Comment: I test it ! if you have  "peter bull team tunnel rat 50 20 30" it will return [50, 30, 20], but it should return [30,20,50]. OP asked for  "last 3 fields backwards "

Comment: @ncica you are right, I didn't read a question and just see the expected output, answer updated.

Comment: no worries, it's just a well-meaning comment :) @bharatk